# Why do 3 pip modules exist after a virtual environment created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After creating a virtual environment, I found three pip modules:

```
pip, pip3, pip3.6
```

What's the purpose of the redundancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redundancy gives you access to the *version specific* pip binary when you have multiple Python versions installed. Python does the same, you have `python3` and `python3.6` binaries, perhaps even a `python` binary <sup>(*)</sup> that points to the same version.

If you were to install, say, Python 2.7, you'd have `python`, `python2` perhaps <sup>(*)</sup>, and `python2.7`. Similarly, `pip` installed into Python 2.7 would at least give you `pip2` and `pip2.7` versions too.

In a virtualenv this may not make much of a difference, but in theory you could add the `bin` directory of the virtualenv directory to your `PATH` variable, at which point typing in `pip` could find the binary in the virtualenv or in a different directory, but `pip3.6` would be much more specific.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Whether or not Python 2 is available as `python2`, or Python 3 is available as `python` is something the OS packagers decide, or if you are in a virtualenv. Traditionally, Python 2 has not been installed under `python2` but some systems have made this switch and make `python` point to a Python 3 release by default.

Answer (score 0):

The redundancy is there because Python has more than one version and is not compatible with each other. P

> It matters for people that have multiple installations of python, and
>   particularly on systems where those multiple installations share the
>   same prefix, such as Unix, where you'd have /usr/bin/python for 2.x
>   and /usr/bin/python3 for 3.x, and consequently /usr/bin/pip for 2.x
>   and /usr/bin/pip3 for 3.x.

Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4j1f3x/do_i_use_pip_or_pip3_or_pip34_to_install_packages/d32uo4i/)